# How to keep record of user input in loop

Tags: python-3.x

How to keep track of user input while loop asking user input?

```
  while a!=b:
    useerinput=input("enter")
    l = []
    l.append(userinput)
    c = ''.join(l)
    print(c)
  else:
    exit()
```

expected output
enter a
a
enter n
ab
enter c
abc
enter d
abcd

....

Comment: Can you show where variables a & b are defined?  If a != b at the start of the loop, they don't change in the while loop so I can't see how the loop ever exits. `l = []` needs be before the loop starts.  As it is it is reset to an empty list every time through the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The list is being assigned to the value of the empty list in every iteration `l = []` so it will never increase in size. It needs to be declared before the while loop. Also the variables `a` and `b` are not assigned a value inside the loop so it will enter an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example in case you've difficulty understanding what other people have already suggested:

```
a=input()
b=input()
l=[]
while a!=b:
    userinput=input("enter")
    l.append(userinput)
    c = ''.join(l)
    print(c)
    a=input()
    b=input()
```

If you don't need `a` and `b` and you just want to exit the loop when the user inputs an empty string (i.e. the user presses ENTER):

```
l=[]
userinput=input("enter")
while userinput != "":        
    l.append(userinput)
    c = ''.join(l)
    print(c)
    userinput=input("enter")
```

Hope it helps.